# Problems using remote state backend in GCP - gsc bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage

a week ago we are having problems using the remote state backend. When are using this code:

```
terraform {
backend "gcs" {
bucket = "bucket-terraform_tfstate"
prefix = "terraform/state"
}
```

And this is the error:
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: googleapi: Error 403: user@xxx does not have serviceusage.services.use access to the Google Cloud project., forbidden

We have this problem in all customer and all projects.The roles are ok, if we try to access the bucket from the console (gsutil list) we can access.
We try in old projects where this code works and we have the same error.
If we use the local state we don't have problems.
Can anybody help us?
Thank you

We expected find a solution to the problem

Comment: Can you check that the servcie account, under which the terraform is being executed (i.e. Cloud Build service account, or any other), has required roles against that GCS bucket? Bear in mind that the service account under discusion may be different from one used in a terminal.

Comment: Hello, we are not using a SA, we made the connection using our users. That users have permissions to create and use buckects.